# Extracting the signature of a LaTeX3 function

Tags: latex3

Is there a built-in function that can extract the signature of a `LaTeX3` function ?

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% From https://www.alanshawn.com/latex3-tutorial/#defining-and-using-variables
\cs_set:Npn \my_concat:nn #1#2 {
    #1,~#2
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand\givesignature{m}{???}

\begin{document}

Signature of \verb#\my_concat# : \givesignature{\my_concat}

% Output expected here: nn #1#2

\end{document}
```

Comment: what input do you want, `\my_concat:nn `  or just `\my_concat` ? if the latter, what output do you want if multple `\my_concat:????` are defined?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: There is no (accessible) register of all defined macros.

Comment: but you didn't answer the second part, what result if there are multple commands of that form (how would tex even find them?)

Comment: note `\my_concat:nn` is just  a name, and `:` is just a letter so your question is like asking for all commands that start `\abc`

Answer (score 2):

There might be

```
\my_concat:
\my_concat:n
\my_concat:nn
\my_concat:nV
\my_concat:nnn
\my_concat:w
```

and so on *ad infinitum*. Well, no, because of the hardwired limitation to nine arguments; but you get the idea.

And there is ***no*** way to ask TeX for a list of all macros whose name starts with `\my_concat:`.

Comment: you could get such a list in luatex by looking at the `tex.hashtokens()`  table.

Comment: @egreg My need is to obtain the signatures typed in the source code. I will play with a Python script.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Can you give à little proof if the concept? Playing with LuaTeX would be also easy.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, LuaTeX exposes the current state of the hash table, but that wouldn't solve the problem anyway. Which one would you take if there are many functions with the same base name?

Comment: @projetmbc ask David, he told me how to do it: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62769558#62769558

Comment: @egreg yes, you are quite right, the idea sounds odd.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This does the job for the moment. Thanks for this.